# Dictionary runtime (Codility Test)

Tags: python

I tried a codility sample question, answering in python. I am not getting 100 score because it failed to finish in time on large data set.

**The following is the question:**

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   The first covering prefix of array A is the smallest integer P such
>   that 0 ≤ P < N and such that every value that occurs in array A also
>   occurs in sequence A[0], A[1], ..., A[P].

For example, the first covering prefix of the following 5−element array A:

```
A[0] = 2  A[1] = 2  A[2] = 1
A[3] = 0  A[4] = 1
```

is 3, because sequence `[ A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3] ]` equal to `[2, 2, 1, 0]`, contains all values that occur in array A.

**My answer is:**

```
def ps ( A ):
    N = len(A);
    if N == 0: return -1
    bit = {}
    for i in range(N):
        if not A[i] in bit.keys():
            bit[A[i]] = 1
            P = i
    return P
```

**Result:**

It doesn't give me 100 for this question because it thinks my algo is O(N**3), and failed test cases are

```
random_n_log_100000 
random test 100 000 elements and n/log_2 n values.  10.025 s.   TIMEOUT ERROR 
running time: >10.02 sec., time limit: 9.82 sec.

random_n_10000 
random test 10 000 elements and values. 1.744 s.    TIMEOUT ERROR 
running time: >1.74 sec., time limit: 1.10 sec.

random_n_100000 
random test 100 000 elements and values.    10.025 s.   TIMEOUT ERROR 
running time: >10.02 sec., time limit: 9.94 sec.
```

**Analysis:**

1. At first I believe my code is O(N) as I assume the key part of my code, A[i] in bit.keys(), has constant run-time, i.e. O(1). But perhaps on large data set, the hash function gives a lot of collision so the runtime is no longer O(1)?
2. Does O(N**3) means O(N^3)? I have this question because I have seen other post where codility report an N square algo as O(N^2). So I suppose they will be consistent in their report?
3. If they really think my answer is O(N^3), then is it reasonable because my code only run past their time limit by less than 1 second? Here I assume their time limit is for an O(N) algo because this is what they request in the question. If that is the case, I can't see why an O(N^3) algo is just >1 sec slow??

Answer (score 9):

`bit.keys()` is a list. Testing if an element is in a list is O(n). 
On the other hand, testing if an element is in a dict is O(1). 
So change

```
if not A[i] in bit.keys():
```

to

```
if not A[i] in bit:
```

With this change, I believe your algorithm is O(n).

(Without the change, I believe your algorithm is O(n^2), **not** O(n^3).)

Answer (score 0):

```
Tried C# code. dont know if it will work for higher values



 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {2,1,1,0,3};
        int i ,n=A.Length;
     for (i= 0; i<n;i++)
    {
        if (A.Contains(i))
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            int p = i;
        }


    }
     Console.WriteLine("p not found");

    }
}
```